# Multiple bib files not compiling

Tags: bibtex, pdftex

I have all my references separated into multiple .bib files. When I try to compile my document - only the first bib file is used and the others are ignored. Here is a basic example with just two bib files:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\title{Agricultural Crop Characterization using Spatio-temporal Scattering Properties of Polarimetric SAR data and a Deep Learning Framework.}
\author{Shauank De}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\input{0_Problem_Statement}
\input{1_introduction}
\input{2_Science}
\input{3_Methodology}

\section{Science Background}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{References/Proposal_Agri , References/polsar}
\end{document}
```

It only pulls information from whichever bib file is listed first. I even tried using sharelatex - and I have the same result.

Sharelatex link:   https://www.sharelatex.com/project/59e1b9dad294f4676c032167

Here is my log file:

```
Process started: bibtex.exe "SD_Agri_2017"

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9)
The top-level auxiliary file: SD_Agri_2017.aux
The style file: IEEEtran.bst
White space in argument---line 11 of file SD_Agri_2017.aux
 : \bibdata{References/Proposal_Agri,
 :                                    References/polsar}
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
Database file #1: References/Proposal_Agri.bib
Repeated entry---line 38 of file References/Proposal_Agri.bib
 : @article{zhang2009mapping
 :                          ,
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "da2008land"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "lee2004unsupervised"
-- IEEEtran.bst version 1.14 (2015/08/26) by Michael Shell.
-- http://www.michaelshell.org/tex/ieeetran/bibtex/
-- See the "IEEEtran_bst_HOWTO.pdf" manual for usage information.
Warning--empty journal in wilkinson2006crop

Done.
(There were 2 error messages)

Process exited normally
```

Can someone point me to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

I discovered the source of the error. You can't have spaces in the `\bibliography{References/Proposal_Agri , References/polsar}` command.

The correct command is:
`\bibliography{References/Proposal_Agri,References/polsar}`

Comment: Side-note: Thanks, weird \latex bug for wasting my morning.

Comment: Morning wasted? The log file tells you that the white space is the reason.

Comment: One of the many times in life I've wished I was smarter :( Now that you point it out, ts clear as day. But I was in a frantic panic rush this morning.